# El software de Arduino emula hardware?

Tags: arduino, hardware, emulación

Buen día comunidad de StackOverflow!

He estado investigando en internet sobre el software oficial de Arduino para determinar si puede o no emular hardware, es decir, necesito saber si el software de Arduino emula en un entorno virtual como se comportaria cualquier microcontrolador en la realidad (como lo hace el programa Proteus por ejemplo).

He leido en bastantes foros en inglés y español pero no doy con la solución a mi inquietud entonces me gustaría que algún miembro que haya utilizado anteriormente me confirme si puede o no emular software ya que la información que he leido es muy vaga incluso en su página oficial.

> **Observación:** Pregunto especificamente por el software Arduino ya que he leido varios "arduino's simulator" que son programas de terceros en los cuales de momento no estoy interesado.

Agradecido de antemano por toda la colaboración que puedan prestarme.
Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, el software de Arduino es solo un entorno para programar lineas de código y después poder transferirlo a la placa. No tiene un simulador como Proteus diría yo.

Saludos.

Comment: Si estuve leyendo mucho y llegué a la misma conclusión. Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Un saludo!